# Find and replace text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA in Excel and have a fairly simple issue. I need to search for specific text string `Bath` in Column `B`.  If it exists, then I need to replace specific text string `KCab` in Column `C` of the same row with `BCab3`.  I need to run or loop this until it checks all the cells in Column `B`.

Here is what I have so far, which is not working:

```
Sub Correct_Attribute_Suffix()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B3", ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("BATH", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then Currentcell.Offset(, 1).Value = Replace("KCab", "K", "B")

    Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to show us some code. What have you tried? Also, do not ask 2 questions in 1 question

Comment: It was not a duplicate...I edited the question to include my attempted code upon the request of @ David Brossard

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Comment: Yes @SiddharthRout , I closed it as the first duplicate I could find that was remotely close to a replacement operation. As there was no code beyond a vague software spec. I had little to go on.

Comment: And pleaseeeeeeeee do not hardocode row values... `"B65536"`

Comment: @MikeV - That actually **was** a duplicate of your original question. If you do not provide specifics then expect to get answers that may not be specific to your own individual situation.

Comment: No worries @jeeped. Just wanted to be sure as was surprised to see my name. Anyways, I tired raising the bug and it got closed :D

Answer (score 1):

This is just a Find/FindNext operation using offset and replace to accomplish your attribute suffix adjustment.

```
Sub Correct_Attribute_Suffix()
    Dim fnd As Range, addr As String

    With ActiveSheet.Range("B3", ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
        Set fnd = .Find(What:="BATH", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
            addr = fnd.Address
            Do
                fnd.Offset(0, 1) = Replace(fnd.Offset(0, 1).Value2, "KCab", "BCab3", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
                Set fnd = .FindNext(After:=fnd)
            Loop While addr <> fnd.Address
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```